# Error in Cache-Control header

Tags: bug, status-declined, caching

All pages (that I tested) on Stack Overflow have this header:

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=60
```

The problematic part is the `public` keyword which should be `private` instead. According to [RFC 2616](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html), Section 14.9.1:

> **public**
>
> Indicates that the response MAY be cached by any cache, even if it
>         would normally be non-cacheable or cacheable only within a non-
>         shared cache. (See also Authorization, section 14.8, for
>         additional details.)
>
> **private**
>
> Indicates that all or part of the response message is intended for
>      a single user and MUST NOT be cached by a shared cache. This
>        allows an origin server to state that the specified parts of the
>        response are intended for only one user and are not a valid
>        response for requests by other users. A private (non-shared) cache
>        MAY cache the response.

In short the `public` keyword is allowing well-behaving proxies to cache the content sent to a *logged-in user* and display it to *other people*.

This is most definitely what is causing issues like [Co-workers logged in as me when viewing question I asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29459/co-workers-logged-in-as-me-when-viewing-question-i-asked) and others (I've seen at least another similar report, but I can't find it anymore).

**EDIT**: there was an error in my original post in which I implied that `public` was fine for unregistered users. This is not true since the proxy would be instructed to send the unregistered page (no user name, etc) to - possibly - registered users. It should be `private` in all cases.

Comment: But all responses also carry a `Vary: *` header, thus instructing proxies not to send cached versions if user Cookies: or even just the User-Agent: mismatch.

Answer (score 4):

Mario is correct - we also use the Vary: * header which according to http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.6

> A Vary header field-value of *
>   always fails to match and subsequent
>   requests on that resource can only be
>   properly interpreted by the origin
>   server.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.44

> A Vary field value of * signals that
>   unspecified parameters not limited to
>   the request-headers (e.g., the network
>   address of the client), play a role in
>   the selection of the response
>   representation. The * value MUST NOT
>   be generated by a proxy server; it may
>   only be generated by an origin server.